# Can't access Ip camera from local pc

Tags: networking, router, ip, ip-camera

My setup is as follows:

- TP-Link Tapo C310 Camera connected to Nova WiFi extender (192.168.5.214)
  *Nova WiFi extender connected by Lan cable to router (192.168.1.1)

I am unable to connect to this camera as my pc is connected by Lan to the router not the nova WiFi extender.

I have tried various different port forwards on both the router and nova with no luck. If I connect my pc to the nova then all is good but this is not a long term solution.

Any help would be great.

*Screenshot of Internet setting on Nova*

[image: Screenshot of Internet setting on Nova]

[image: Screenshot of bridge description on nova]

Comment: Welcome! There are two things that would make sense here: a) Moving the nova extender into the routers' subnet (192.168.1.0/24 presumably) or b) Configuring a route on the router and the nova extender. Could you check whether you can configure the extender to get a DHCP config from the router?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a photo to the original question of the Internet setting on the nova. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, this leads me to believe that the nova is actually in what is often called 'router mode', while receiving the upstream connection using DHCP. Could you please check the description on the 'bridge' mode? If it's an acceptable solution to merge both network segments into one LAN then this could solve your initial issue.

Comment: Thanks again. I have added a photo of the description of bridge mode to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what I have understood from the Nova product manual, your setup and problem situation I'd switch the Nova extender to Bridge mode. As the name suggests, this will get rid of the network segregation (which you are trying to work around using port forwarding). Essentially, you'll have one large LAN spanning the devices connected to the router and the nova mesh network.

Since the nova extender would become a simple wireless bridge, it will not be possible for it to perform some of the services as shown in the info message. Hovewer, your router likely already provides these.

Since the router (instead of the nova extender) will advertise network configuration to the camera, its IP address will change. Therefore you'll have to check the routers DHCP leases or scan the network. Perhaps the app of the camera already supports something like this.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that this evening. What you say make sense, effectively I'm running two separate networks and neither will talk to each other so the bridge merges them into one network.

Comment: Thanks jvda. That has solved it by putting the nova into bridge mode. It has also solved a few other issues that I wasn't aware of too.

Comment: Excellent! If you feel that these problems might be applicable to other nova users, would you mind commenting these?